# Как сохранить данные в файл формата .txt?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть данные(имя и время прохождения уровня),как сделать чтобы эти данные сохранялись в файл формата .txt,но сначала имя,а потом результат?

вот код с этими данными:

```
private List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

    public void SaveRecord()
    {
        var record = new Record();
        record.TimeInSeconds = 180 - i;
        record.Username = textBox1.Text;
        records.Add(record);
    }
```

Comment: нужен чистый вид данных или, например, JSON?

Comment: чистый(под моим понятием это в котором они есть,в том и записываются)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать класс StreamWriter:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("results.txt"));

records.ForEach(x => sw.WriteLine($"Username: {x.Username}, TimeInSeconds: {x.TimeInSeconds}"));
sw.Close();
```

Можно использовать File.WriteAllText + StringBuider:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
records.ForEach(x => sb.AppendLine($"Username: {x.Username}, TimeInSeconds: {x.TimeInSeconds}"));
File.WriteAllText("results.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Можно использовать File.WriteAllLines + LINQ:

```
File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", records.Select(x => $"Username: {x.Username}, TimeInSeconds: {x.TimeInSeconds}"));
```

Выбирайте любой из вариантов (если что, то это не все возможные варианты).

Comment: он не записывает в файл

Comment: разобрался,теперь записывает